# Don't turn on Laptop on sleep mode

Tags: 22.04

When I put my laptop on sleep mode, it doesn't turn on even though the numlock is on, but the screen doesn't turn on. My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04 . Thank you for your guidance

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend